# React use setState to update book shelf

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have starter template which I convert to React site for learning and I don't know how to use setState to update book shelf. In the project I have App.js file in it there is changeShelf function I want to use the setState function to update the current state instead of use BooksAPI.getAll in BooksAPI.update function to do the same job.

```
changeShelf(book, shelf) {
    BooksAPI.update(book, shelf).then(() => {
        BooksAPI.getAll().then((books) => {
            this.collectBooks(books)
        })
    })
}
```

App.js file:
https://codeshare.io/5wK36x

BooksAPI.js file:
https://codeshare.io/adDo9g

Comment: `this.setState({ books })` ?

Comment: In state i don't have books instead i use currentlyReadingBooks, wantToReadBooks & readBooks Also i can not use this directly since i have multiple books and the changes made of just one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to remove the book from the current shelf. Then add the book to the right shelf.

You can change `changeShelf` to the following:

```
getShelfWithoutBook(shelf, book) {
    return shelf.filter(item => item !== book);
}

changeShelf(book, shelf) {
    this.setState({
        currentlyReadingBooks: this.getShelfWithoutBook(this.state.currentlyReadingBooks, book),
        wantToReadBooks: this.getShelfWithoutBook(this.state.wantToReadBooks, book),
        readBooks: this.getShelfWithoutBook(this.state.readBooks, book)
    });
    if (shelf === 'currentlyReading') {
      this.setState({
        currentlyReadingBooks: this.state.currentlyReadingBooks.push(book)
      });
    } else if (currentShelf === 'wantToRead') {
      this.setState({
        wantToReadBooks: this.state.wantToReadBooks.push(book)
      });
    } else if (currentShelf === 'read') {
      this.setState({
        readBooks: this.state.readBooks.push(book)
      });
    }
}
```

This probably can be written a lot less repetitive, but I hope it's easier to understand this way.

Edit: Or you could re-use your `collectBooks` method:

```
changeShelf(book, shelf) {
    // collect all books in one list:
    const books = [
        ...this.state.currentlyReadingBooks, 
        ...this.state.wantToReadBooks, 
        ...this.state.readBooks
    ];
    // remove the book you want to change: 
    const booksWithoutThisBook = books.filter(item => item !== book);
    // update the shelf of the current book:
    book.shelf = shelf;
    // re-add the changed book:
    const booksWithUpdatedBook = [...booksWithoutThisBook, book];
    // re-run the collectBooks method:
    this.collectBooks(booksWithUpdatedBook);
}
```

Comment: If i want to add this than i will repeat a lot of code since most of what you write is already part of collectBooks function check here https://codeshare.io/5wK36x

Comment: I have updated my answer, `changeShelf` now re-uses `collectBooks`.